# In ASP.NET Core project the page url changes after form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

I am developing a project in .NET 8 version so I customized page urls in my language.

While submitting the form it works ok but when I return the model to view my page's url changes to my action name.

The default page url (route) that I have form.

```
https://localhost:7135/article-settings/chosee-author/3/
```

This is the form I submitted.

```html
<form id="createForm" asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="AddNewAuthor" method="post">
    <input class="form-control mb-1" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" asp-for="ArticleId" />
</form>
```

And this is the page url after form submitted

```
https://localhost:7135/article-settings/save-author/
```

All actions have different route templates, maybe that can be problem but if I don't add custom route templates request can't find the action.

So don't want to change my page url after submit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to your description, do you mean you want to redirect to `https://localhost:7135/article-settings/save-author/` after Settings/AddNewAuthor method? Do you want to pass some variable to the article-settings/save-author method?

Comment: Please add information for the AddNewAuthor action in your Settings controller as it may help in getting a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

```
 <script>
     var pageUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
     history.replaceState(null, title, pageUrl);
 </script>
```

This method allows you to change your page url and reload page without re-submitting your form.

Answer (score 0):

do redirect in submit function

```
public IActionResult AddNewAuthor(model ...) 
{
   ...
   RedirectToAction("ChooseAuthor",new {id = model.id})
}
```

or use javascript

```
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('createForm'));

        fetch('@Url.Action("AddNewAuthor", "Settings")', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                //success
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
</script>
```